# How use Threading.Thread.Sleep for panel visible

Tags: vb.net

I want to show up `panel17.text = "complete"` before the panel3 fadeout ..
and the code I made panel13 fadeout before label17.text appear ..
if anyone can help ??

```
Private Sub Button5_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles SubmitAdd.Click

    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(IDadd.Text) Or _
        String.IsNullOrEmpty(NamaAdd.Text) Or _
        String.IsNullOrEmpty(PasswordAdd.Text) Then

        Label17.Text = "filled all"
    Else
        Try
            Label17.Text = ""

            Dim tambah As String
            tambah = "INSERT INTO [TblAdmin] VALUES ('" + IDadd.Text + "','" + NamaAdd.Text + "','" + PasswordAdd.Text + "')"
            Dim CMD As New SqlCommand(tambah, con)
            con.Open()
            Dim Nama As SqlDataReader = CMD.ExecuteReader()
            Label17.Text = "complete"
            con.Close()
            Me.TblAdminTableAdapter.Fill(Me.DataBase_SystemDataSet1.TblAdmin)

        Catch ex As Exception
            con.Close()
            MessageBox.Show("data is exists", "failed", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        End Try

    End If
    Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
    Me.Panel3.Visible = False
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if it would work, but you could try calling 'Label17.refresh' just before the 'Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)' line